# How do I install Firefox with preconfigured toolbars?

Tags: firefox, automation, rhel-6

I have a custom Red Hat 6 kickstart disc which installs and configures a workstation as a control system.

We use Firefox (at the moment: the 31.4.0 long-term release) to allow the system maintainer to access various http-based configuration pages or parts of the system like routers or RAID controllers.

For operator convenience, all these pages are set as pre-loaded bookmarks.

I've already figured out where the bookmarks that get loaded into each new profile live: in Firefox 31, it's in /usr/lib64/firefox/browser/defaults/profile/bookmarks.html

But, as of a few releases ago, all the toolbars and menus are hidden by default. We want the Bookmarks Toolbar always shown so that administrators can readily see what maintenance options are available. This is relatively minor, but it *is* a quality-of-life thing that I'd like to fix.

So, what I want to do is install a Firefox with the Bookmarks Toolbar pre-filled (done!) and visible by default (I don't know how to do this). These are systems that potentially support multiple administrator accounts, all of which should have a properly-configured Firefox on first login.

**How do I change Firefox's default configuration to make the Bookmarks Toolbar visible by default to new users?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension to deploy Firefox customizations to your users:

> Need to customize Firefox? With the CCK2 Wizard, you can create custom Firefox configurations that can be installed as extensions or deployed with AutoConfig.

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/cck2wizard/